# Mesmo script em varios gameobjectos

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5

Tenho quatro gameobjetos na tela (ativos) cada um com o mesmo script, mas renomeados para não ficar exatamente igual.

Meu problema é que quando aciono via touch um deles o outro é quem obedece ao comando. Sem sequência lógica alguma.

Simplesmente um recebe os comandos de todos e, quando eu o destruo, outro passa a receber os comandos (de todos também)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e mostrar como está o código?

Comment: Seleciona o GameObject e da uma olhada no inspetor, verifica se no inspetor está relacionado o script correto para o mesmo objeto. Mals ai, não consegui comentar, não tenho pontuação suficiente para comentar.